# How to show any message through impala shell script

Tags: shell, impala

I am facing issue to show any message in impala script running through Shell script. I am migrating a code of hive to impala and facing.
In hive, was  using !sh echo " ---- any message ----" to show any message the excel file but in impala this is not working. I used the same syntax but no message was shown to me in the output excel file.
Please help.

Thanks,
Deepak
+91-9911714417

Comment: You can follow this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62174395/in-hql-scripts-we-use-sh-echo-new-line-for-the-same-want-to-know-the/62204541#62204541

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62174395/in-hql-scripts-we-use-sh-echo-new-line-for-the-same-want-to-know-the?noredirect=1#comment110285535_62174395 Please refer this to display message from impala scripts